# cross browser issue in joomla website

Tags: css, joomla

I am having cross browser issue in joomla website i.e http://great.server279.com/greatofficiants.
Website is working all fine in firefox and in rest browsers its not appearing the same.

Problem is when we go into EXCLUSIVE VIDEOS block whole images of videos are appearing on chrome,safari,ie  but it is appearing all well in firefox.

```
div id="vtab-1" class="vcase" style="display: block;
div id="vtab-2" class="vcase" style="display: none;
```

Comment: I have seen your id="vtabs" in chrom and found there is no display propery appearing in inner divs, please share your way of implementing display property to get it resolved.

Comment: http://www.seoonlinehelp.com/stack.txt

Comment: all content of index has been pasted.. please help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with stepCarousel.js file. the Js file is conflict in the cross browser. can you explain me that which JS are you using. So that I can help you more